# parbox in math mode creating extra spaces between characters

Tags: math-mode, spacing, parbox

```
\framebox{

   \parbox[t][2cm]{2cm}{

      $S: <NM, <Other> >$ 
    }

   }
```

Will output:  `S :< N M, < other >> with extra spaces between '> >' and between 'N M' and '< N'`

How to remove those spaces ?

Comment: (1) always provide a full but minimal examples that others can just copy and test as is, (2) add an image of the output you get. I do not see any changes in spacing comparing a parbox of width 2cm and one of width 4cm (which does not introduce the line break)

Comment: you have not provided a usable example but a relation such as `<` uses `\thickmuskip` which is stretchy by default so like inter-word spaces is of variable length in justified paragraphs (in or not in a parbox)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I guess you want `\langle` and `\rangle` instead of `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common error to mistake `<` and `>` for angle brackets. You *might* use the glyphs for angle brackets, but you need to change their “math nature”, which is of a relation symbol.

The fact that the formula is in a `\parbox` is irrelevant.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\la}{\mathopen<}
\newcommand{\ra}{\mathclose>}

\begin{document}

1. Wrong usage: $S: <NM, <Other> >$ 

2. Correct spacing: $S: \la NM, \la Other \ra \ra$

3. Better shape: $S: \langle \mathit{NM}, \langle \mathit{Other} \rangle \rangle$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why the “strange” spacings in 1? Actually they're not at all unexpected. Indeed, the colon `:` is a relation symbol as well, so TeX doesn't add space between it and `<`. After `<` comes an ordinary symbol, so thick space is placed between them. Only the space after punctuation is inserted between `,` and `<`, but thick space is added between `<` and `O` and between `r` and `>`. No space between the final `>` and `>`, because they're relation symbols.

Using `<` and `>` as opening and closing atoms fixes the spacing, but not the shapes in 2.

The most common symbols in this context are `\langle` and `\rangle` as shown in 3, where I also used `\mathit` to denote a cluster of letters, and not multiplication between variables.

Comment: ok thanks, but `mathit` is actually doing nothing (not reducing the spacing between the chars)

Comment: \textit{} worked! by leaving the italic styling inside the $$ and removing the spaces

Answer (score 1):

Unrelated to `\parbox` spacing around relations (`\thickmuskip`) is stretchy by default, so like inter-word spaces will stretch or shrink to justify paragraphs

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$S: <N$
aaa\linebreak aaa

$S: <N$
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\linebreak aaa


$S: <N$
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\linebreak aaa

$S: <N$
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\linebreak aaa


\end{document}
```

You could set `\thickmuskip` to a fixed length or prevent stretching with a `{}` group: `${S: <N}$`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

${S: <N}$
aaa\linebreak aaa

${S: <N}$
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\linebreak aaa


${S: <N}$
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\linebreak aaa

${S: <N}$
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\linebreak aaa


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `${S: <N}$` is simply not working, spaces are still there

Comment: @SSSOF see the last image in this answer, spaces in `${S: <N}$`  are frozen to natural size and will not stretch. Note you can run my examples and check you get the same result, you have not provided any usable example.